# How to conduct User Interface Testing and Instrumented Unit Testing on an Android Service with visible layout - specifically a floating widget?

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, junit, android-testing, expresso

Basically the question.

I'm currently trying to test a floating widget service that looks like the Messenger Bubble head. I have read the documentation on Expresso UI testing, however, the case I'm dealing with is a bit complicated.

Considering that the floating widget is an Android Service, it is not an Activity and hence cannot use ActivityScenario to test. While so, as the service utilizes a view, I need to conduct UI test on it. How do I test the floating widget using Expresso? I have imported and added all required dependencies to the gradle files, the problem is now the direction to test.

To specify further, what I wish to test include:

1. The floating widget service view is visible on the user screen
2. Clicking the floating widget will open another expanded view for the user to choose different buttons on. Thereon I will test the button clicking.
3. Test whether the floating widget service destroys itself (via stopService) on calling it
4. Other minor test (movement, touch, click, background, auto-alignment)